# Unable to install gcc-8 g++-8 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, gcc, g++

I am trying to install gcc-8 g++-8 on my Ubunutu 20.04 but I cannot as shown below. Any advice?

```
sudo apt install gcc-8 g++-8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'clang-8-doc' for regex 'g++-8'
Note, selecting 'python-clang-8' for regex 'g++-8'
Note, selecting 'clang-8' for regex 'g++-8'
Note, selecting 'clang-8-examples' for regex 'g++-8'
Note, selecting 'libclang-8-dev' for regex 'g++-8'
E: Unable to locate package gcc-8
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to accomplish this:

- Install GCC and G++ using by doing:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository universe 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install gcc g++
```

- You can do it with dpkg if it doesn't work:

```bash
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-8/gcc-8_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-8/g++-8_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i g++-8_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb gcc-8_8.4.0-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt --fix-missing install
```